# How to attach hostname to the message body when using sendmail?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm testing the following ssh script where in if ssh fails due to not reachable, authentication, I want to attach the exception or the at least the host name to the message body which I have failed to figure out how to do so, for now it only sends a mail with text and this is not helping to identify which host failed as it goes through a loop of hosts in the input file.

```
import csv,subprocess,paramiko,time,socket,smtplib,base64
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from conf import SMTP as smtp
from datetime import date
IP = {}
Type = {}
Host = {}
Username = {}
Password = {}
hostname = {}
status = {}
msg = MIMEMultipart()
password = 'something'
msg['From'] = "servicedesk@mail.com"
msg['To'] = "user@mail.com"
with open('test.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvinput:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvinput)
    for item in reader:
        IP = item['IP']
        Host = item['Hostname']
        Username = item['Username']
        Password = item['Password']
        Type = item['Type']
        date = date.today()
        if 'Network' in Type:
            try:
                # Create instance of SSHClient object
                remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()
                # Add untrusted hosts
                remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
                # Initiate SSH connection
                remote_conn_pre.connect(IP, username=Username, password=Password, port=22)
                print("SSH connection established to %s" % IP)
                # Use invoke_shell to establish an 'interactive session'
            except:
                print("Can't Connect to %s" % Host)
                msg['Subject'] = "SSH Failed"
                body = "Failed to connect to server"
                msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))
                server = smtplib.SMTP("mailserver.com",587)
                server.starttls()
                server.login(msg['From'],password)
                server.sendmail(msg['From'],msg['To'],msg.as_string())
                server.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could attach the hostname to the body message (as you mentioned), instead of just a print statement;

```
except:
    print("Can't Connect to %s" % Host)
    msg['Subject'] = "SSH Failed"
    body = "Failed to connect to server, hostname: {}".format(HOST)
```

and if you want to keep the same formatting method;

```
except:
    print("Can't Connect to %s" % Host)
    msg['Subject'] = "SSH Failed"
    body = "Failed to connect to server, hostname: %s" % Host
```

Comment: That actually did the job!, but I receive two emails when I run this, one with no subject or message body, another with correct content.

Comment: Hmm, from the code you've posted theres no reason it should send twice, are there other parts of the script that aren't shown here?

Comment: No, I copied pasted the entire script from the file.